# How to Read ORC File in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-data-integration-hub

How to Read ORC File in informatica Power Center.
I tried via reading in flatfile or ODBC Junk Character is getting return

Comment: May be possible if hive is MapR, CLoudera, or hortonwork distribution. You may alos need Power exchange for hadoop...  https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/361262?language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

It seems you will need a PowerExchange adapter for HDFS.

Please refer [PowerExchange for HDFS Overview](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powerexchange-adapters-for-informatica/10-4-0/powerexchange-for-hdfs-user-guide/introduction-to-powerexchange-for-hdfs/powerexchange-for-hdfs-overview.html) for detailed information and
[ORC Data Types and Transformation Data Types](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powerexchange-adapters-for-informatica/10-4-0/powerexchange-for-hdfs-user-guide/data-type-reference/orc-data-types-and-transformation-data-types.html) for ORC related details.